# Determine a basis for each of the following subspaces of $F^3$ for the given F. With solution

Tags: abstract-algebra

(a) For $F = \mathbb Z_7$, the solution space of the system is

$$x - 3y +z = 0$$

$$2x - 6y + 2z = 0$$

Solution:

Before solving this system of equations, we note that the second equation is a multiple of the first. Hench we have $x = 3y - z = 3y + 6z$. Putting $z = t$ and $y = s$, the typical solution is $[x, y, z]=s[3,1,0] + t[6,0,1], s, t, \in \mathbb Z_7$. The solution space is $sp([3,1,0],[6,0,1])$. Since the only solution of $\lambda_1[3,1,0] + \lambda_2[6,0,1] = [0,0,0]$ is $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$, these vectors are linearly independent and we conclude that $\{[3,1,0],[6,0,1]\}$ is a basis.

---

I don't get how they got this step: $x = 3y - z = 3y + 6z$.

Could someone explain please (Howed they get $3y+6z$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Z}_7$, we just have that $-1 = 6$.

Comment: Can I leave the solution as $x = 3y-z$, so it would $[x, y, z] = s[3,1,0] + t[-1,0,1]$?

Comment: Sure you can!!!